# How do I add a section title in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

I need a label above every section in my Collection View. I've tried simply dragging a label into my header space above my prototype cell, but every time I run the app, the label is not visible.

Any help?

Answer (score 106):

To add the custom label above every section in UICollectionView, please follow below steps

1. Enable the section header in UICollectionView

[image]

2. Add a new file of type UICollectionReusableView
3. In the storyboard change the class of section header in UICollectionViewCell to the newly added file of type  UICollectionReusableView.
4. Add a label in section header of UICollectionViewCell in storyboard
5. Connect the label in the section header to the UICollectionReusableView file

   ```
   class SectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
       @IBOutlet weak var sectionHeaderlabel: UILabel!
   }
   ```
6. In the ViewController add the below code

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

       if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader{
           sectionHeader.sectionHeaderlabel.text = "Section \(indexPath.section)"
           return sectionHeader
       }
       return UICollectionReusableView()
   }
   ```

Here "SectionHeader" is name of the file added to type UICollectionReusableView

Comment: Great step by step. The item 6 need a override prefix.

Comment: In 1.,3., & 4. you refer to UICollectionViewCell, however I think it should be UICollectionView.

Comment: You will need this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282447/unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier-cell-must-register-a-nib-or-a-class-f

Comment: You will also need to register the SectionHeader class with the collectionView:-self.collectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader")

Comment: Shouldn't "SectionHeader" be the reusable identifier set in storyboard?

Answer (score 45):

Implement `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` and supply a dequeued UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader containing your label. If this is a flow layout, be sure also to set the `headerReferenceSize` or you still won't see anything.

Comment: Example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p462collectionViewFlowLayout/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 36):

If you want a programmatic solution in Swift 4.2, you can do the following:

1. Setup the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
2. Make custom UICollectionReusableView subclasses with whatever views you want defined. Here's one for a header, you can create another for a footer with different characteristics:

   ```
   class SectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
        var label: UILabel = {
            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.textColor = .white
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
            label.sizeToFit()
            return label
        }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            addSubview(label)

            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method with the custom views:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView { 
       if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeader
            sectionHeader.label.text = "TRENDING"
            return sectionHeader
       } else { //No footer in this case but can add option for that 
            return UICollectionReusableView()
       }
   }
   ```
4. Implement the referenceSizeForHeaderInSection and referenceSizeForFooterInSection methods. Header method shown below for example:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40)
   }
   ```

Comment: You need to register the supplementary view - `self.collectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question that predates compositional layouts (as introduced in WWDC 2019 [Advances in Collection View Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215?time=1959)), but in case you are trying to do this with compositional layout and diffable data sources:

1. First, you would register your `reuseIdentifier` for your header view, like normal. E.g., if using a NIB:

   ```swift
   collectionView.register(
       UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil),
       forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "header",
       withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView"
   )
   ```

   That presumes you have (a) a NIB for this supplementary view; and (b) a type with outlets for that view:

   ```swift
   class HeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
       @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
   }
   ```

   (Obviously, if you prefer programmatically creating your header view, then feel free to do that. You just want to make sure that you register that reuse identifier with your supplementary view.)
2. Then, when configuring your compositional layout, you would create a “boundary supplementary view” (i.e., a [`NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutboundarysupplementaryitem/)) and set your section’s [`boundarySupplementaryItems`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199089-boundarysupplementaryitems/):

   ```swift
   let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize (…)
   let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
   let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(…)
   let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
   let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

   let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize (
       widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
       heightDimension: .estimated(44)
   )

   let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
       layoutSize: headerSize,
       elementKind: "header",
       alignment: .top
   )
   header.pinToVisibleBounds = true

   section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header]

   let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

   collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
   ```
3. Then, assuming you are using a diffable data source, you would make sure to configure the [`supplementaryViewProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3255142-supplementaryviewprovider/) of your [`UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/):

   ```swift
   supplementaryViewProvider = { [weak self] collectionView, kind, indexPath in
       guard let self else { return nil }

       let text = sections[indexPath.section].id
       let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView", for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
       header.label.text = …
       return header
   }
   ```