# Optional UICollectionView Header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, header, uicollectionviewlayout

I've implemented the following method in the `UICollectionViewDataSource` in order to return a header for my `UICollectionView` section.

However, I'd only like to return a `header` view if `hasOthers` is true. The below code throws the following exception in this case:

`Exception  NSException *   "the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xaa02564b411fe771> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (<UICollectionReusableView: 0x7ff43f577700; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000026484a0>>)" 0x000060000321f240`

I also can't return `nil` from this method as it doesn't return an `Optional`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
        if !hasOthers {
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
        if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as? OrderCVHeaderView {
            sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .white
            return sectionHeader
        }
    }
    return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

I followed this example when implementing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57666316/4909000

How can I return an optional header, only if `hasOthers` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview): This method must always return a valid view object. If you do not want a supplementary view in a particular case, your layout object should not create the attributes for that view. Alternatively, you can hide views by setting the isHidden property of the corresponding attributes to true or set the alpha property of the attributes to 0. To hide header and footer views in a flow layout, you can also set the width and height of those views to 0.

Comment: An effective way to let a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` know that a header (or footer) view should not exist for some sections  is to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method `collectionView(layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` method and return `.zero` when there is no header. In this case, no header will be used at all and `collectionView(viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)` won't be called for those sections.