# TableView : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, exception, swift5

Even though I have written the code as given below and In the storyboard , identifier has been set for SortTableViewCell, it is showing throwing an exception :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier SortTableCellID - must register a nib or a class for
>   the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SortTableCellID", for: indexPath) as! SortTableViewCell
    cell.sortValues.text = sortArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

The code ain't working after the Xcode(Xcode 10 -> Xcode 11) updating to its latest version, it seems to show an error while running the same code.As a newbie to Swift, please somebody help me to sort this out.

Comment: Are you using Xib for tableview Cell? or in storyboard?

Comment: No, I am not using Xib and the error popped up after the updation of xcode to its latest version

Comment: Did you search at all?  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618084/299924) pretty quickly.

Comment: I tried that one out @trojanfoe but not helpful.

Comment: Maybe you set the Restoration ID rather than the cell identifier.

Comment: Nope, I have set the cell identifier itself rather than the restoration ID @vadian

Answer (score 1):

As the crash clearly says

> You need to register nib or xib before use as cell in tableview

The system is not able to identify the cell for the tableview(like which cell be used to display in tableview).

**If you are not using xib**

If you are not using xib then please verify the following things...

- You've specified the Reuse Cell Identifier in storyboard.(Select cell from tableview in you have created)

[image]

- You have specified a class for tableview cell.

[image]

**When using xib**

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SortTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SortTableViewCell")
```