# How to solve a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error?

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, swift5, sigabrt

I'm having an issue with my app, it keeps coming up with a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error every time I build it. I've looked for a solution but nothing seems to work, any ideas? I'm new to this!

[Error In consolse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8FUK.png)

Comment: Have you enabled a breakpoint? Do you have some code to share?

Comment: Check your collectionview identifier is correct and also check that number of items in return correct value. Put a breakpoint in them function..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282447/unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier-cell-must-register-a-nib-or-a-class-f)

Comment: Do not show pictures of code (including console output). Copy it and paste it into the actual question, as _text_. Thanks.

Comment: Show your UICollectionViewController code please. A question without the relevant code is pointless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a prototype cell in your collection view. This article might help you work through the issue.

https://theswiftdev.com/2018/04/17/ultimate-uicollectionview-guide-with-ios-examples-written-in-swift/

Without looking at the code I'm guessing you should be able to go into the storyboard select the cell and add in the cell name using the inspector on the right.

Answer (score 2):

### **What Does “Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT” Mean?**

The error SIGABRT stands for “signal abort”. It’s a signal that’s sent by iOS to a running app, that immediately quits the app because of a runtime error. It essentially means your app has crashed…

### there might be possible causes

**Check Your Outlets:**

1. You created a new view controller in Interface Builder, and set it up
   with a few UI elements like buttons and labels
2. You connected these UI
   elements to your code by using outlet properties, which creates a
   connection between a property of your view controller and the UI
   element in Interface Builder
3. At one point you changed the name of the
   initial outlet property and your app started crashing with a SIGABRT
   error

**Check The Stacktrace**

if Xcode won’t show you any helpful error messages for a SIGABRT crash, try typing commands in the console area to debug such as **`help`** and **`bt`**:

**`bt`** is very useful to see the current call stack (also called “backtrace” or “stacktrace”).

**Make An Exception Breakpoint**

Here’s how you can set an exception breakpoint:

1. Go to the Breakpoint navigator in Xcode, by using the tabs on the left
2. Click on the bottom-left +-button and choose Exception Breakpoint
3. Leave the default settings as-is (although they’re helpful to customize)
4. Run your code

When an exception is thrown, execution of your app halts. You can now use the debugger to inspect values, step through the code, and use LLDB commands. When possible, Xcode will take you to the line of code that caused the exception.